# Filter a List<T> based on another list that each instance of T contains

Tags: linq, list, lambda, many-to-many, filtering

So I have a collection of objects in one list, but each object in that list contains another list.

Consider the following:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(string parentName)
    {
        this.ParentName = parentName;
    }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}
class Child
{
    public Child(string name)
    {
        this.ChildName = name;
    }

    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

By the nature of the application, all Parent objects in the list of parents are unique. Multiple parents can contain the same child, and I need to get the parents that contain child x.

So, say the child with ChildName of "child1" belongs to both parents with ParentName of "parent1" and "parent5". If there are 100 parents in the collection, I want to get only the ones that have the Child with ChildName of "child1"

I would prefer to do this with a lambda expression but I'm not sure where to start as I don't really have to much experience using them. Is it possible, and if so, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Child` class has defined an equality operation by implementing `IEquatable<Child>`, you can do this easily by using a lambda, the `Enumerable.Where` method of LINQ and the `List.Contains` method:

```
var parents = new List<Parent> { ... }; // fully populated list of parents
var child = null; // the child you are looking for goes here
var filtered = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Contains(child));
```

You can now iterate over `filtered` and perform your business logic.

If the `Child` class does not have an equality operation explicitly defined (which means that it will use reference equality rules instead of checking for identical `ChildName`), then you would need to include the "what passes for equal" check into the lambda yourself:

```
var filtered = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.ChildName == "child1"));
```

Note: *There are of course many other ways to do the above, including the possibly easier to read*

```
parents.Where(p => p.Children.Count(c => c.ChildName == "child1") > 0);
```

*However, this is not as efficient as the `Any` version even though it will produce the same results.*

In both cases, the lambdas very much "read like" what they are intended to do:

1. I want those parents where the Children collection contains this item
2. I want those parents where at least one of the Children has `ChildName == "child1"`

Comment: Thanks for the added detail to your answer. This has helped quite a bit, and after looking up the IEquatable<T> interface, I have decided to go along with that method. Works like a charm! Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.ChildName == "child1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do it

```
IEnumerable<Parent> parentsWithChild1 = parents.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.ChildName == "child1"));
```